# How to run a PHP script using a Cron job

Tags: php, linux, bash, ubuntu

I'm having a PHP script which I want to run every 2 minutes using a Cron job in Ubuntu. I'm getting the following error:

```
bash: */2: No such file or directory
```

I've completed all steps below to set up a Cron job.
Please help me to resolve the error, I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

1) Write this command in my terminal: `where is php`

Output:
`php: /usr/bin/php /usr/bin/X11/php /usr/share/php /opt/lampp/bin/php /usr/share/man/man1/php.1.gz`

2) Run a PHP script every 2 minutes:
`*/2 * * * * /usr/bin/php  /opt/lampp/htdocs/kyrill/filetest.php`

Output:
`bash: */2: No such file or directory`

Comment: first: have you add the path correctly to the cron? second: have you add at the very top of your script the script type? in your case should be like this #!/usr/bin/php

Comment: olso add php **** php /usr/bin/......

Comment: @alvaro if i want to run php on terminal then i have write this command on terminal php /opt/lampp/htdocs/kyrill/filetest.php and it execute it successfully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
0/2 * * * * curl http://[your_id:port]/kyrill/filetest.php
```

Comment: with this also it is showing the same error bash: 0/2: No such file or directory

Comment: Would you mind to set it * * * * * curl http://[your_id:port]/kyrill/filetest.php ?

Comment: no i dont i have any but it is also not working given the same bash error

Comment: No, please, don't add an extra layer of obfuscation. You don't need Internet to run a local command.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like you are executing the crontab directive.

Execute

```
 crontab -e
```

to edit your cron jobs. Then add this line at end of the file

```
 */2 * * * * /usr/bin/php /opt/lampp/htdocs/kyrill/filetest.php
```

Comment: yes i will directly run on terminal but when i apply your approach it gives me something like this error E486: Pattern not found: 2 * * * *

Comment: Follow this link, could help you https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-cron-to-automate-tasks-on-a-vps

Comment: are you using vim?

Comment: Seems that you are using vim, follow this link to get help https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/installing-and-using-the-vim-text-editor-on-a-cloud-server